# Declare and initialize a 2D Array in Typescript and keep type checking in following lines of code

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

This is the format I've found around the internet:

```
  twoDArr: string[][] = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'x']]
```

but when I `console.log(twoDArr)` I get a typescript error `Parameter 'twoDArr' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Why?

Note: I am not interested in using any. I want to keep my typing.

Answer (score 1):

Your type is valid, also you can use the generic format to type your arrays :

```
const twoDArr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'x']]
const twoDArr2:Array<Array<string>> = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'x']]
console.log(twoDArr)
```

When you type `[string]` you are describing an tuple, an array with a fixed size, here 1.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFDuIAiBBATmmBeGBtXA5AIYEA0MBARmRcAQLrmEAeNBr99AUKJLAsnRoATAC4hRAJ4AeCTOhoAlmADmAPjXY8hEuSps6jPOzYduvCCAA2AUwB0VkCoAUA1BgCUQA)

Comment: so is this a typescript bug/incomplete feature then?

Comment: The more often I see it, the more I realize that Array<> is more readable than [] ... because the syntax with [] is not always intuitive.